# crystal report group footers togeteher

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

normally crystal report display

```
Details section
Group footer section 1
Details section
Group footer section 2
```

But I need 1 details section

```
Details section
Group footer section 1
Group footer section 2
```

Is there anyway achieve this.

please don't suggest subreport.

Comment: Please suppress the last details section

Comment: can you show sample data?

Comment: How do you actually choose Group Footer Section? Is there a formula on Suppress?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that.

When you make group by some column then you have sections like this

```
group header
detail
group footer
```

In your case you have to suppress group header, after that right click on group footer and select "insert section below" and then you achieved sections like this

```
details 
group footer a
group footer b
```

Same way you can make several group headers too or several detail sections.